# Using Javascript or CSS, how can I add additional space at the end of a block of text, but only if it does not start on a new line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Let's say I have some text, with a `(more)...` link at the end of each paragraph. It ends up looking something like this:

```
This is just a test paragraph. Click on the more link for more info. (more...)
```

Now I'd like to add some space between the link and the paragraph text, so I wrap the link in a `<span>` tag and push it to the right with a `margin-left: 10px`:

```
This is just a test paragraph. Click on the more link for more info.     (more...)
```

The problem here is, if the text wraps right on the more so that it shows up on a second line by itself, it will look indented:

```
This is just a test paragraph. Click on the more link for more info. Push it down!
     (more...)
```

When the desired output should be:

```
This is just a test paragraph. Click on the more link for more info. Push it down!
(more...)
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect using either Javascript or CSS?

**Side note:** It is possible to achieve this effect by removing the `<span>` tag and using `&nbsp`characters to push the more linke to the right with proper text wrapping, but this is a solution I'd like to avoid unless there is no other choice. Or I could use Javascript to insert the `&nbsp`'s before the span, but that's not exactly a nice solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a `width` on the `paragraph` and then float the `span` to the right.

That way the `(more...)` remains on the the right always.

Not exactly what you are after but I think it looks decent.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WFuBd/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the content before the link in a `span` and apply a `margin-right` to that, you'll get the desired effect. (Unfortunately, this, too, is not really a nice solution)

Comment: Doing it backwards, clever! But yes, not exactly elegant :).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 2 div's. Div one floats left, div two floats right... Make sure overflow=hidden on div one, and (more...) is on div two.

[div 1 lots of text i.e.: 300px] [div 2(more...) i.e.: 40px]

It will look perfect every time. You'll have to play around with it to look right, but it'll work. You could then just do a little jQuery when you click more...to show the rest and hide 'more'.